# How do *you* explain macro behaviour in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'd be interested to know what strategies people are using to work backwards from the results of a model (from observed emergent behaviour) to try to answer the question: what is it about individual turtles that has led to this macro behaviour?

Comment: In my experience in ABM the behaviors of the agents are the bit that we know explicitly. We designed them. The emergent stuff is the less known. Is this for an essay?

Comment: This is a wonderful question, but it may get closed for being off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may need to ask on it https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/netlogo-users/info instead.

Comment: (You might also ask on Programmers.SE if the question gets closed here.)

Comment: By the way, this is really a general question about agent-based modeling.  It's not specific to NetLogo.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking, "How can you guess what rules govern agents [turtles], given the macro-level behavior?"?  Or are you asking, "Given that you have the source code, how to do you figure out what it is about the source that generates the macro-level behavior?"?

Answering the first question is very hard, often.  I don't have suggestions.

Answering the second can be hard, too.

One strategy is to experiment with different initial configurations, or experiment with different rules in agents [turtles].  If you have no guesses about what to vary, make arbitrary choices at first, until you begin to have guesses, or even vague intuitions.  Then vary the code in ways that will explore whether your guesses are correct, and in ways that will allow you to refine your guesses.  This strategy won't always work.

Perhaps it might be useful to try to think through how you *could* generate the macro-level behavior, if that's what you wanted to produce.  You might not have any idea of what an answer might be--this would amount to answering the first question above--but if you do, it might lead to guesses that you could use for the preceding strategy.

Answer (score 2):

I do this when I am debugging because sometimes I get unexpected macro-behaviour and I need to determine whether it is real or an error. Typically what I would do is set the random seed then look at which agents are involved in the behaviour and when (ticks in NetLogo) it occurs. I would then rerun the model and stop it a few ticks beforehand and inspect the agents that I know are going to be involved in the behaviour to see if there's something unusual about them or their environment. Macro behaviour typically occurs because of the interactions of agents, environment and events so I am trying to determine WHAT those elements are, before seeking to explain how they combine to create the behaviour. Once that's done, I can usually trace the code (dropping in a print statement and inspecting the relevant agents) to work out how it occurred.